# unable to send selected rows of datagrid into database but send text of System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to select rows of Data-grid into DemoTest in SQL
it has no error in starting it but as i check the table in SQL i see the text showed in image. it doesn't send the data in the DataGrid but it send the code system.Windows.Controls.TextBlock

using GetCellContent is wrong? or should i

using WPF Entity FrameWork.

```
private void btn_SendWorkOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 

        {


        DemoTest Dtest = new DemoTest();
        CheckBox mChkBox = new CheckBox();


        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridInsRep.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {

            mChkBox = DataGridInsRep.Columns[0].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]) as CheckBox;

            if (mChkBox.IsChecked == true)
                {

                Dtest.MCode = Convert.ToString(DataGridInsRep.Columns[2].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]));
                Dtest.MName = Convert.ToString(DataGridInsRep.Columns[3].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]));

                Dtest.McName = Convert.ToString(DataGridInsRep.Columns[5].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]));
                Dtest.PDesc = Convert.ToString(DataGridInsRep.Columns[6].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]));
                //Dtest.McCode = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridInsRep.Columns[4].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]));
                database.DemoTests.Add(Dtest);

                }

            }
        database.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("may check it");
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj2Di.png)

Comment: You really ought to be looking into mvvm and working with bound data rather than iterating any ui controls. At best you'll have very fragile code the way you're doing it and maintenance will be much more costly than if this was MVVM. It is different and it takes time to learn but it's a way better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because

```
DataGridInsRep.Columns[2].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i])
```

returns the Column Content which is internally `TextBlock` (if not override by Cell Template).

Change the code to

```
var codeTextBlock = DataGridInsRep.Columns[2].GetCellContent(DataGridInsRep.Items[i]) as TextBlock;

Dtest.MCode = codeTextBlock.Text;
```

You should do it for other properties.

However, another perspective here is that why are you fetching the data like this. If the DataGrid's ItemSource is bound to Collection of class, then following code is more readable:

```
var itemsSource = DataGridInsRep.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
if (itemsSource != null)
{
    foreach (var item in itemsSource.OfType<YourClass>())
    {
        Dtest.MCode = item.MCode;
        //...
    }
}
```